# Android - how to return result from an activity to a fragment other than the caller in jetpack navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

In my project I have a single activity architecture with jetpack navigation. I have just added a new camera feature, which is an activity. I need to open this Camera Activity from Fragment 1 but I would like to receive result in Fragment 2. On back press from Fragment 2 I would like to return to Fragment 1. Both Fragment 1 and Fragment 2 are in the same nested nav graph.

How to best do it? AFAIK the Camera Activity can't be a part of a current nav graph, there can only be one activity per nav graph. Only thing I can think of is opening the Camera Activity with *registerForActivityResult* and receiving the result from camera in Fragment 1 and manually opening Fragment 2 passing the result, but I would like to avoid the intermediary and open Fragment 2 directly from the Camera Activity.

Comment: If the user cancels taking a picture (e.g., by pressing the system back button), do you want the user to be on Fragment 1? If that is indeed the case, then Fragment 1 needs to be the one to start the camera activity for a result, right? So why not just `navigate` if you get a valid result to Fragment 2, passing it the data?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes, Fragment 1 needs to start the camera activity, but I was hoping to navigate from camera activity to Fragmet 2 directly in order to avoid unnecessary view switching/flickering. AFAIU when receiving the result, I would need to show Fragment 1, even if for a short moment and with some loading mask, and only then open Fragment 2. UX-wise this seems like a bad idea to me. Unless there's a way that it would look to the user as if Fragment 2 was opened directly after finising camera activity?

Comment: Have you actually tried it? Calling `navigate` in the activity result callback should instantly move you to the other fragment.

Comment: @ianhanniballake My bad, I don't know why I assumed it would show Fragment 1 first. In such a case I guess it's the best approach, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you cannot navigate to `Fragment2` in `Activity1` from `CameraActivity` directly as both have different navgraphs
Potential solutions

1. Instead of calling `CameraActivity` from `Fragment1`, delegate this to host activity and once it sets result, the host activity will registerForActivityResult and control nav graph to show fragment2 with data!
2. Right before navigation, open `Fragment2` with some argument say `open_camera` as `true`, then `Fragment2` would launch `CameraActivity` and wait for result in `onCreate` if open_camera is true!

Comment: I am trying with the second approach, but I am unable to open camera activity without showing Fragment 2 for a split second first. Where to put opening the camera activity so that Fragment 2 is not yet drawn and shown to the user?

Comment: in `oncreate` you could directly call `cameraactivity`

Comment: Tried that, but it still showed Fragment2 first. Nevertheless, I am going to go with my original approach, since as it was pointed out by ianhanniballake, my objections about it were unfounded. Thanks.